# Grails/Acegi disabled users question

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have a Grails app with acegi security, and I just found some users with their "enabled" field in false, when they were set to true after an approval process.

My question is: May it have happened because of a maximum login attempts reached ? If so, where is it configured ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no support for maximum login attempt checking in the plugin. If it's implemented it may be custom code but it'd probably use an event handler. If it's custom code you'd probably have beans defined in resources.groovy, and/or possibly bean property changes in BootStrap.groovy. If it's using an event, the callback(s) would be in SecurityConfig.groovy - see http://www.grails.org/AcegiSecurity+Plugin+-+Acegi+Events